# Adam wiser than angels - meaning and implications

Tags: animals, parashat-bereishit, malach-angel, adam

> אָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן מֶה הָיְתָה חָכְמָתוֹ? כְּשֶׁבִּקֵּשׁ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לִבְרֹאת אֶת הָאָדָם ... אָמַר לָהֶם **אָדָם שֶׁאֲנִי רוֹצֶה לִבְרֹאת חָכְמָתוֹ מְרֻבָּה מִשֶּׁלָּכֶם**, מֶה עָשָׂה כִּנֵּס כָּל בְּהֵמָה חַיָּה וְעוֹף וְהֶעֱבִירָן לִפְנֵיהֶם, **אָמַר לָהֶם מַה שְּׁמוֹתָן שֶׁל אֵלּוּ, לֹא יָדְעוּ**, כֵּיוָן שֶׁבָּרָא אָדָם הֶעֱבִירָן לְפָנָיו אָמַר לוֹ מַה שְּׁמוֹתָן שֶׁל אֵלּוּ, אָמַר, לָזֶה נָאֶה לִקְרוֹת שׁוֹר, וְלָזֶה אֲרִי, וְלָזֶה סוּס, וְלָזֶה חֲמוֹר, וְלָזֶה גָּמָל, וְלָזֶה נֶשֶׁר, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וַיִּקְרָא הָאָדָם שֵׁמוֹת [Bamidbar Raba 19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.19?lang=bi&with=Bamidbar%20Rabbah&lang2=en)

What did the sages mean by saying that God testified that Adam is wiser than angels? Does it mean "wiser in all aspects" or specifically in the realm of naming animals? What wisdom is naming animals?

Comment: The commentaries say that the name of something in loshon hakodesh speaks to it's intrinsic nature. It's not arbitrary. Honing in on something's essence is wisdom that Adam had and not the angels. You'd be satisfied with sources that say that? Or you want something else.

Comment: @robev A good start. Now. Angels know Hebrew AND can't name animals, hence they don't know animal intrinsic nature. Please explain what does this mean.